# Inserting data using Sleepy Mongoose to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, sleepy-mongoose

I have a strange problem when I try to insert the data into the MongoDB using SleepyMongoose API. I have installed curl, openSSL, pyMongo, Phyton and everything is configured. I am running SleepyMongoose Server, I am connected to my database locally but when I try to insert some data into the data base using this commands:

```
curl --data "docs=[{"x":1}]" "http://localhost:27080/foo/bar/_insert"
```

I am getting error

```
enter code here{"ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "couldn't parse JSON: [{x:1]]"}
```

Database foo is created and visible in MongoDB but collection bar is not created.

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. System which I am using is Windows 8.1 x64

Ok somehow I think I have managed the situation but I have the following problem...
I am getting the error curl [7] failed to connect to port 80

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes to surround your JSON so that the embedded double-quotes are preserved:

```
curl --data 'docs=[{"x":1}]' "http://localhost:27080/foo/bar/_insert"
```

Comment: When I have done this I have got another error message {"ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "missing docs"}